# Estimating treatment effects, 2 Group Pre-Post Matched Analysis

Tags: sas, generalized-estimating-equations, pre-post-comparison

I am trying to estimate the treatment effect for a pre/post w 2 groups design, subjects were measured on healthcare utilization 1yr before and after the intervention (non-random assignment).   The dependent vars are  cost/utilization measures that are right skewed, some zero-inflated.   To control for the vastly different distribution in many covariates, case subjects are matched to controls 1:1.  For the dependent variables that are not zero-inflated I am using GEE in SAS PROC GENMOD with either Gamma or Negative Binomial distribution, however, with the zero-inflated dep vars, GEE is not available and am seeking advice on which SAS statistical proc are available that would accommodate the right skewed zero-inflated dep vars and the matched design.

Thanks in advance, Brandon Zagorski